# Can somebody help me with EventHandling on WXWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

while trying to make some first progress with **WXWidgets** in **C++** I´ve got on a problem.

As youre able to see in the Code below, I´m trying to Handle an Button-Click-Event from an **WXWidget-Application.**

The main Problem is that the dedicated Method `TopPanel::OnClick()` doesnt run. (Nothing is print to console)

Possible Errors:

- Problem with my implementation of PanelEvents
- Wrongly installed WXWidgets (probably not cuz it does compile without any errors)

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
};

class TopPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
    TopPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxSize size);
private:
    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent &);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum ButtonID {
    button_id_first = wxID_LAST + 1,
    button_id_other
};

bool App::OnInit()
{
    MainFrame* frame = new MainFrame("Nova Loader", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(25, 25, 25));
    this->SetFocus();

    TopPanel* pnl_top = new TopPanel(this, wxSize(500, 30));
    wxPanel* pnl_bottom = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 270));
    wxButton* btn_load = new wxButton(pnl_top, button_id_first, "Load");
    wxButton* btn_exit = new wxButton(pnl_top, button_id_other, "Exit");
    wxBoxSizer* s1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    s1->Add(pnl_top, 0, wxALL, 5);
    s1->Add(pnl_bottom, 1, wxALL, 5);

    wxBoxSizer* s2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    s2->Add(btn_load, 0, wxRIGHT, 5);
    s2->Add(btn_exit, 0);

    wxBoxSizer* s3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    s3->Add(s2, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT | wxRIGHT | wxTOP, 3);

    pnl_top->SetSizer(s3);
    pnl_bottom->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(45, 45, 45));

    this->SetSizerAndFit(s1);
}

TopPanel::TopPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxSize size) : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, size)
{
    this->SetSize(500, 30);
    this->SetId(wxID_ANY);
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(45, 45, 45));
}

void TopPanel::OnClick(wxCommandEvent &e)
{
    std::cout << e.GetId() << std::endl;
}

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TopPanel, wxPanel)
EVT_BUTTON(button_id_first, TopPanel::OnClick)
EVT_BUTTON(button_id_other, TopPanel::OnClick)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Thanks to everyone trying to help me!

~ Tim

Comment: The method `TopPanel::OnClick()` is called successfully when I execute your program. It successfully prints the `id`. So your claim that `TopPanel::OnClick()` doesn't run is not correct. Try recompiling/rebuilding  the project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and effort of testing, I'll rebuild the project as you said and try it again.

Comment: You're welcome. There is also an option of using dynamic event table using `Bind` instead of static event table as shown in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73092716/12002570) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, your given example successfully calls the `OnClick` method. So your claim that `OnClick` is not called is not correct.

Now that being said, with newer(modern) `wxWidgets` you can also use **dynamic event table** using `Bind` instead of *static event table* as shown below. The changes made are highlighted as comments in the below given program:

```
class TopPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
    TopPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxSize size);
    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent &);
    //removed wxdeclare_event_table from here as no longer needed 
};
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    //other code as before
//---------------------------------------------vvvvvvvv----------->let wxwidgets choose the id for you 
    wxButton* btn_load = new wxButton(pnl_top, wxID_ANY, "Load");
    //bind btn_load to onClick 
    btn_load->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &TopPanel::OnClick, pnl_top);
//---------------------------------------------vvvvvvvv------------>let wxwidgets choose the id for you
    wxButton* btn_exit = new wxButton(pnl_top, wxID_ANY, "Exit");
    //bind btn_exit to onclick 
    btn_exit->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &TopPanel::OnClick, pnl_top);
    //other code as before
}
```

Below is the complete working example that uses `Bind`:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
};

class TopPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
    TopPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxSize size);
    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent &);
    //removed wxdeclare_event_table from here as no longer needed 
};

enum ButtonID {
    button_id_first = wxID_LAST + 1,
    button_id_other
};

bool App::OnInit()
{
    MainFrame* frame = new MainFrame("Nova Loader", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(25, 25, 25));
    this->SetFocus();

    TopPanel* pnl_top = new TopPanel(this, wxSize(500, 30));
    wxPanel* pnl_bottom = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 270));
//---------------------------------------------vvvvvvvv----------->let wxwidgets choose the id for you 
    wxButton* btn_load = new wxButton(pnl_top, wxID_ANY, "Load");
    //bind btn_load to onClick 
    btn_load->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &TopPanel::OnClick, pnl_top);
    wxButton* btn_exit = new wxButton(pnl_top, wxID_ANY, "Exit");
    //bind btn_exit to onclick 
    btn_exit->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &TopPanel::OnClick, pnl_top);
    wxBoxSizer* s1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    s1->Add(pnl_top, 0, wxALL, 5);
    s1->Add(pnl_bottom, 1, wxALL, 5);

    wxBoxSizer* s2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    s2->Add(btn_load, 0, wxRIGHT, 5);
    s2->Add(btn_exit, 0);

    wxBoxSizer* s3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    s3->Add(s2, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT | wxRIGHT | wxTOP, 3);

    pnl_top->SetSizer(s3);
    pnl_bottom->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(45, 45, 45));

    this->SetSizerAndFit(s1);
}

TopPanel::TopPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxSize size) : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, size)
{
    this->SetSize(500, 30);
    this->SetId(wxID_ANY);
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(45, 45, 45));
}

void TopPanel::OnClick(wxCommandEvent &e)
{
    std::cout << e.GetId() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"toppanel onclick called"<<std::endl;
}
//no need for event table entries here
```